# Installation of IBM RAD 7.5 fails with couldn't create jvm

Tags: java, ibm-rad

I am trying to install IBM RAD, while installation, I am getting this error -
couldn't create jvm
Why Does JVM terminates?

Comment: can you post full error message?

Comment: post the full error message. if there is a get error log button/show details/advanced or something, you can get the stack trace from there and post that. that would be helpful

Comment: just error message : "could not create java virtual machine"

Comment: Synchronizer Eclipse p2 returned error status 1, for more information go to the protocols

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that environment variables(**_JAVA_OPTIONS**) were set improperly.

Also you did not specify which version of java did you use? you must use Java 5.0+ in the context of Rational Application Developer v7.0 or higher.

Refer this [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21327744) and this [also](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21410196)